# top left image not aline with the menu

Tags: html, css

In my page, the top left image which is logo2.jpg shifts to right, and I want it to be at the same line of menu that is below it. How can I do that?

The page is here, if it helps:

http://www.dilyurdu.com

```
#logo {
margin:0 auto; width: 975px; position:relative;
}
#top {
position:relative; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:95px;background:url("vocab_dosyalar/back2.jpg") top repeat-x;
}
#logoicerik {
position:absolute; top:2px; 
}
#logoicerik2 {
position:absolute; top:2px; left:357px;
}

    <div id="top">
         <div id="logo" >   
              <div id="logoicerik"><img src="vocab_dosyalar/logo2.jpg" alt="easylang" style="border:0px;"/></div>
              <div id="logoicerik2"><img src="vocab_dosyalar/slogan.jpg" alt="the easiest way to learn english"/></div>
              <div class="header-info" style=" margin-right:1px; margin-top:15px" ></div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: try removing `margin:0 auto;` from .container in css and set it like; `margin: 0px 180px` and adjust as you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `container` class has `width: 960px` but your **wraper**(sic) class has `width: 990px`

so you need to make sure they both have the same width: I'd recommend making both 990px by changing the width of **container**

```
.container {
  WIDTH: 990px;
}
```